# UIView constraint not showing same result on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I am using Interface builder to design my app with the Any x Any dimension. The program displays it correct on all devices (iPhone 4, 5, 6), but on the iPad it seems the constraint isn't working.

Here is an example on how it looks on the correct devices (iPhone 6s):

[image: Display shows correct]

However, when I run it on iPad I get the following:

[image: Display shows incorrect]

The constraints for the description view are:

[image: Constraints of Description view]

The constraints for the header view are:

[image: Header view constraints]

As you can see, the iPad version doesn't put the "Description" field underneath the header image like the iPhone version does. I tried resetting the constraint and making sure I didn't alter the constraint in another dimension which is not Any x Any. I have no clue why it's still not placed correctly. The console and interface builder don't give any warnings / errors. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you tried to put a constraint wich stick the bottom of your red view to the bottom of the global container with a distance equal to 0?

Comment: (1) it would help to show us how what the constraints are (2) if a storyboard, are you getting any warnings about the constraints? (3) when you run, do you get any constraint warnings in the console?

Comment: Kokodelo the red view is the contentView which is equal to its superview (the blue view which is an UIScrollView). The contentView has all constraints matching the superview.

 i updated the question thanks Lou ! :)

Comment: "it seems the constraint isn't working" The constraints are working _perfectly_. They are wrong (for the desired results), but they are working.

Comment: Matt you're right, I changed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you created your constraints, but try this:

- Create constraints for your image:

  1. Trailing Space
  2. Leading Space
  3. Top Space
  4. Aspect Fit
  5. Aspect Ratio
  6. Make sure your image is clipped to subviews.
- Keep your description view constraints.

You can change constraints 4 and 5. Just make sure your constraints knows the image container size and make the image fit.

If the container is smaller than the image and the image is bigger than the container, the entire image might show. But this way your constraints won't know the actual image size.

Comment: I followed the constraints from 1-4 for the image. I added a height constraint which always makes the container have a fixed height of 250. The ratio used is Aspect fill, causing the image to always fill the container of height 250. The problem still is showing. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Try not loading the image and setting an background color. Let me know what happens. If the color is placed correctly, this means your image is bigger than the bounds. If the color is not in the right place, means your constraints is still wrong.

Comment: Wow you're right! I disabled the image and set a background color, the result is that the color is placed correctly and the description too! How is it possible that the image is bigger than the bounds? That shouldn't matter because its aspect fill + a fixed height of 250?

Comment: I got it. The image should allow "clip subviews". Can you edit your answer so I can mark it? :)